# How do I secure "Data at Rest" only allowing Service API to access it from a mobile application

Tags: web-application, mobile

How do I secure data at rest from unauthorized access, but still allowing my application to access the data using user authentication over HTTPS?

My scenario is as follows:

1. Login to application using ID and password (password is hashed using MD5)
2. After authentication from the server, user uploads data to the server
3. User can retrieve that data using the application
4. All data transfer is based on HTTPS
5. Data on the server is not encrypted

My questions are:

1. If I encrypt the data at the location on the server, how do I retrieve it using my client application?
2. Is there any algorithm which allows data to be encrypted and the encrypted data to only be decrypted and retrieved when my application is trying to retrieve data?
3. How do I keep that data secure from getting hacked if someone gets access to the server?

Comment: MD5 for hashing passwords is a big no-no

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate the user or the application when downloading the data? In other words, can other applications download the data provided a successful user authentication, or do you want to restrict it to your application?

Comment: And don't forget the `salt`!

Comment: Are you storing the data in a database or a file system?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten YES i authenticate user , i want to restrict it to my application only

Comment: @schroeder i am Storing data in file system.with a entry of it in database related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Encrypt/decrypt data in the client, then the server is just storing an opaque blob.
2. Have the client transmit a key that the server uses for encryption/decryption.

Any encryption algorithm provides what you want, what matters is key management.  Additionally, if your server is compromised, then encryption at rest only protects against adversaries not able to tamper with your operating environment.  If they can modify the server (which they usually **are** able to do, except for access to backups, etc.) then they can capture the data coming and going.  In that case, only client-side encryption will help.

And seriously, don't use md5 for passwords.  If you're using MD5 for password hashes, you've already put user's data at risk.  Leaked, unsalted, MD5s are basically as good as plaintext these days.  scrypt and bcrypt are considered the state of the art in password hash storage, but even salted SHA-2 will buy you a *lot* compared to MD5.

Comment: can you suggest me any good Algorithum or any good security programs which could be very helpful